# PayPal Adaptive Payments with single item

Tags: paypal

I have developed a small API that uses PayPal Adaptive Payments to create a chain payment.

Here is my current JSON body that I send to PayPal:

```
{
    actionType: "PAY",
    currencyCode: currency_code,
    feesPayer: "SECONDARYONLY",
    memo: product_name,
    receiverList: {
        receiver: [{
            amount: payment_amount,
            email: primary_email,
            primary: true
        }, {
            amount: payment_amount-(0.03*payment_amount),
            email: secondary_email,
            primary: false
        }]
    },
    returnUrl: "http://example.com/payment-success",
    cancelUrl: "http://example.com/payment-cancel",
    requestEnvelope: {
        errorLanguage: "en_US"
    },
    trackingId: product_id
}
```

It works perfectly. The full amount is sent to the primary user, and then 97% of the full amount is sent to the secondary user.

Although, I would like to each of my items so that their quantity is always `1`. My site is dynamic and allows users to create items all the time with their own price, name, etc. I would like to mark the item as `purchased` on my site after someone checks out with PayPal so that no one can buy it again, hence removing the `purchase` button.

I understand how to do that with Webhooks (provided by PayPal), although what if two or more users press the `purchase` button on my website and are checking out with PayPal at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put your own contorl over the concurrency in this case, as PayPal does not provide this uniqueness validation upon payment attempts in adaptive payments.

Here's how you may put the control in the front-end

1. Generate a unique `invoiceId` for each dynamic purchase button on the front-end
2. Collect the payment details (recievers, amount, invoiceID, etc) with your purchase button, and post the payloads to your API action page (when user submit the purchase button).
3. In your API action page, validate & save (into database) the `invoiceId` field to avoid duplicated puschase attempts (placing a status of `ordered`), and then invoke the PayPal `pay` API call to generate the `PAY-KEY`. *Put the `invoiceId` in the `payload:receiver` object for tracking purpose in the PayPal callback and transaction reports*:

   ```
   receiverList: {
       receiver: [{
           amount: payment_amount,
           email: primary_email,
           invoiceId: uniqueId,
           primary: true
       }, {
           amount: payment_amount-(0.03*payment_amount),
           email: secondary_email,
           primary: false
       }]
   },
   ```
4. Buyer is redirected with the `PAY-KEY` and completes the transaction
5. Webhook/IPN triggered and you'd mark your database entry as `purchased`

Note on Step#3,

- In this flow there're actually 3 status of your purchase button: 1-available, 2-ordered, 3-purchased, this way you have control over it always as a single purchase
- Incase buyer drops off(canceling or AFK or closing browser) in Step#4, you may clear the `ordered` status after 3 hours (PayPal `PAY-KEY` lifecycle)

Comment: That does seem like a very logical approach, although unfortunately it would simply just not work. What if a user of my application disliked another user and decided to click on `purchase` for all of their items? Therefore, other users would not be allowed to purchase those items since they would be marked as `purchased` within my DB. Then within another 3 hours, they could simple just click on the purchase buttons again to reinitiate the 3 hours.

Comment: That is just a example and means you may customize any rule in Step#3 by your use case, e.g. make unique `invoiceId-userId` pairs, so that every buyer has one chance to purchase. PayPal (or generally, payment) products won't help any further in this perspective, you need to build a bidding system to make it work then.